# Publish abstract unit tests, to help ensure quality of 3rd party interface implementations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, inheritance

I want to publish and re-use common unit tests for implementations, also to enforce conventions on behavior, constructors and static methods (using Reflection), so that everybody can test custom implementations in his place. In this case, an interface to provide singleton objects (Polly policies) through dependency injection, and registration for DI.

So it is different from regular unit tests, which are only local and test a few standard implementations, or each individually. Is this the correct way, to help developers create correct implementations?

I am currently using only a class library (not a test project), with the *MSTest.TestFramework* Nuget package, and the common test project linked into unit tests of implementations, also have it packaged as Nuget.

I use abstract test classes, where the actual test implementation provides the implementation types (usually through `assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IPolicySource).IsAssignableFrom(t))`).

(Unfortunately, I did not yet find out how to use parameterized test methods with runtime-generated parameters, such as the types from the assembly).

## My example:

```
public interface IPolicySource
{
    string GetName(); // static value or configuration dependent

    IsPolicy PollyPolicy { get; } // singleton instance per IPolicySource instance.
}
```

```
public abstract class PolicySourceTests<TTestClass> 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get types implementing IPolicySource, e.g. from assembly.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract IReadOnlyList<Type> GetTypesToTest(); 

    [TestMethod]
    public void PolicySource_Is_PollyPolicy_Singleton()
    {
        foreach(implType in GetTypesToTest())
        {
            var policySource = (IPolicySource)Activator.CreateInstance(implType);
            var policy1 = policySource.PollyPolicy;
            var policy2 = policySource.PollyPolicy;
            Assert.AreSame(policy1, policy2, "Singleton instance?");
        }
    }
}
```

Unit tests check implementations if:

- the PollyPolicy always returns the same instance when accessed multiple times
- A static `string GetInstanceName()` method exists, which creates the default name (if instance from default constructor).
- For constructors with configuration parameters, a corresponding static `GetInstanceName(cfgValue1, cfgValue2, ...)`method exists, which is used to generate the `GetName()` value.
- All `GetInstanceName(...)` methods return the same name as `new ctor(...).GetName()` for same parameters.

### Conclusions so far:

Advantages:

- Common unit tests for correctness of all custom implementations
- No code duplication

Disadvantages:

- Difficult to navigate to actual test from VS Test Explorer
- Tests hard to read (inheritance)
- Test code not directly available

**Any ideas or best-practices how to implement and distribute common unit tests?**

Comment: I would imagine the best practices are going to be the same for implementing and distributing anything else.  Simply follow those practices.

Comment: "*Unfortunately, I did not yet find out how to use parameterized test methods with runtime-generated parameters, such as the types from the assembly*" - see the [`DynamicData` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.dynamicdataattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2019).

Comment: @DM thanks for the hint on DynamicData! Unfortunately, it can use only static methods, and I need abstract/overridden instance methods for inheritance.

Comment: @ErikHart I might be mistaken, but you should be able to implement [`ITestDataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.itestdatasource?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) to get access at runtime. Meziantou's blog has an article about MSTest with a [section about custom `DataSource`s](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-data-tests.htm#custom-datasource).

Comment: I tried with an own implementation of `ITestDataSource`, but it was impossible to get the actual test class instance or type, only the abstract base type as `methodInfo.DeclaringType` from the `GetData(methodInfo)` parameter. Maybe I can try again with generics...

Comment: It seems like generics were the way to go for dynamic data, like `public abstract class TestClassBase<TActualTestClass> where TActualTestClass : TestClassBase<TActualTestClass>`. I can then create a singleton instance on a static property, to retrieve the test data (it is static anyway, instance methods/props only necessary for inheritance). The advantage is, that generic classes have their own static values per generic type (I get a warning for this from code analysis). This way, I can feed test implementation specific data into the `DynamicDataAttribute`.